Sum of sales of delimiter column
I have a table which contains Item and its Sales.
I need Sum of all items & the column may have delimiter with ",".
How Can I do it in either Power Pivot or Power Query.
Table1
** Expected Output**
Cl_1             Cl_2
Rose               4
Pink,Yellow,Red   17
Louts              3
Green,white    5
Result
Thanking you.

Do you group by data based on other columns? Otherwise, how can we know which rows need to be grouped?

@Ryan Cl_1 contains all items of Table1 with delimiter. I need to sum of those items. lookup is Table1.

what I mean is why we combine Pink,Yellow,Red and do not combine rose and pink? what's the logic of grouping?

@Ryan  C1_1 column grouping by default. I have to sum of those combine items from Table1. Ex. Pink,Yellow,Red  sum is 17.  Rose,Pink sum is 20 etc. I just want to do it in PQ or PP. Thank you Ryan.

In Power Query, perform the following steps:

Duplicate column Cl_1
Split new column to Rows

Merge the new split column with Table_1
Expand table to bring in sales
Group by on Cl_1 with sum:


let
  Source = YourTable,
  #"Duplicated column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(Source, "Cl_1", "Cl_1 - Copy"),
  #"Split column by delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Duplicated column", {{"Cl_1 - Copy", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(","), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Cl_1 - Copy"),
  #"Merged queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Split column by delimiter", {"Cl_1 - Copy"}, Table_1, {"Items"}, "Table_1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
  #"Expanded Table_1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged queries", "Table_1", {"sales"}, {"sales"}),
  #"Grouped rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Table_1", {"Cl_1"}, {{"Cl_2", each List.Sum([sales]), type nullable number}})
in
  #"Grouped rows"


Or via DAX you can create a Calculated Column with:
Cl_2 = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(Table_1[sales]),
    FILTER(Table_1, CONTAINSSTRING("," & [Cl_1] & ",", "," & [Items] & ",") )
  )

